# XML file conversion(deserialization) to Bean(POJO) using Jackson XmlMapper in java

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I want to parse one XML File using XMLMapper of jackson faster xml and convert into a pojo class. I'm done through that but at the end I'm facing problem.

Xml File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title>1st Title</title>
      <link>http://www.eample.com</link>
      <language>en-US</language>
      <pubDate>Thu, 16 Jun 2016 04:37:53 +0000</pubDate>
     <item>
         <title>The DI Wire’s QA With CNL CEO Tom Sittema</title>
         <link>http://www.eample.com</link>
         <description>5 lines description</description>
         <pubDate>Wed, 15 Jun 2016 16:30:07 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>2nd title</title>
        <link>http://www.globest.com/sites/paulbubny/2016/06</link>
        <description>5 lines description</description>
        <pubDate>Wed, 15 Jun 2016 16:28:40 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
 </channel>
 </rss>
```

I just want Item tag's contain. But problem is I am getting only 2nd Item tag's contain.

**`Rss.java :`**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "rss")
public class Rss {

private String version;
private Channel channel;

   //setters & getters
}
```

**`Channel.java :`**

```
public class Channel {

private String title;
private String link;
private String description;
private String language;
private String lastBuildDate;
private String pubDate;
private String atom;
private String generator;
private String href;
private String rel;
private String type;

@XmlElement(name = "item")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "wrapitem")
private List<Item> item;

    //Setters & getters
}
```

**`Item.java :`**

```
public class Item {

private String title;
private URL link;
private String description;
private String pubDate;
private String category;
private String source;
private String guid;
private String isPermaLink;
private String url;

    //setter & getters
}
```

**`Main.java :`**

```
  public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
        module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new xmlMapper(module);                                                                        Rss rss = xmlMapper.readValue(new File("/home/Address.xml"), Rss.class);
        Channel channel = rss.getChannel();
        System.out.println(channel);
        List<Item> item = channel.getItem();
        System.out.println(item);
        if (item != null) {
            for (Item a : item) {
                System.out.println(a.getTitle());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

Output :

```
 2nd Title
 null
```

Please help me to Identify why it giving output like this, first it must be print 1st Title and then 2nd Title instead of that why this code is giving such a output.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you use @XmlElementWrapper on your Item list ? There is no wrapper in your xml file.

Comment: @DimpreJean-Sébastien I removed this after posting, after removing this same result will be coming...

Comment: It's weird it gets your second item title and not your first ..., what happens if you annotate your list with Jackson annotations ( something like @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item") ) instead of the JAXB one ?

Comment: @DimpreJean-Sébastien It is giving same output for that also...Something is missing into that is not recognize. I'm still searching for the solution...

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried to fully initialise an RSS object and serialized it to see if the resulting file is correct ? If this is a mapping problem, serialization might reveal the problem. Also, what's your Jackson version ?

Comment: Yes I serialized it into other file but it will only giving me the second item tag's content and another item tag's content is null...jackson-mapper-asl - 1.8.8 & jackson-dataformat-xml - 2.7.4

Comment: @DimpreJean-Sébastien I think mistake is in pojo classes n their anotations...give solution for how to write pojo classes for that xml file?

Comment: I think you miunderstood what i wanted you to try. I want you to initialize an RSS by code (rss = new RSS(); rss.setVersion("2.0");rss.setChannel(new Channel); ect ...) then serialize it to see how Jackson understand your mapping. Also, it's an rss file so i doubt it, but is there any namespace applied to any item element ?

Comment: How did you manage to fix this ? I am stucked with the same problem